# Write and use a function that takes a mask as an argument and returns a structure

Tags: c, struct, bitmask

I'm new to coding and I am trying to complete this assignment, but I can't get it to work:

> Write and use a function that takes a mask as an argument and returns a structure.

Here is what I've done so far.  Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
typedef enum {
    fast = 1,
    slow = 2,
    strong = 4,
    smart = 8,
    agile = 16,
}Skills;

typedef struct _Team {
int ranking;
char name;
} Team;

Team Alabama;

Team USC;

Team _function (Skills skills);
Team _function (Skills skills) {
    if (skills == (fast | smart)) {
        return Alabama; }
    if (skills == (fast | agile))
        return USC;
    else
        return nil;

}
```

Comment: Please explain what "can't get it to work" means exactly. What are your expected results, what are your actual results, and what are your thoughts about the difference?

Comment: And return `NULL` as an empty struct instead of `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

When you have mask-based enums, you check whether that enum is satisfied or not using the bit-wise AND operator `&`.

So, if you want to check if the skills are fast AND smart, do it like so:

```
if ((skills & fast) && (skills & smart)) {
    // this team has the brains and speed.. possible other stuff
}
```

Alternatively, in this situation, the XOR operator would also be a good candidate:

```
if (skills ^ (fast | smart) == 0) {
    // this team has ONLY the brains and speed.
}
```

Last Note:

Define the enums like this, much easier:

```
typedef enum {
    fast   = 1 << 0,
    slow   = 1 << 1,
    strong = 1 << 2,
    smart  = 1 << 3,
    agile  = 1 << 4,
} Skills;
```

---

**EDIT:**

OK, since this is an assignment, let me go through some trouble explaining how this works:

As am sure you know, your enums look something like this (Binary):

```
(00001)
(00010)
...
(10000)
```

Now, using the bit-wise OR operator `|`, you were able to merge two skills together:

```
   00001
OR 01000
   _____
   01001
```

Then, we can check if that new multi-skill enum has some specific skill using `&`:

```
    01001
AND 01000
    _____
    01000 != 0 (aka true)
```

To go to a more advance level, we use XOR, which by definition, sets the resulting bit to `0` if the two bits are equal:

```
    01001
XOR 01000
    _____
    00001 != 0 (aka true)

    01001
XOR 01001
    _____
    00000 == 0 (aka false)
```

Comment: It should also be mentioned that `nil` is not the correct return type to indicate "no structure".